# Pretend file on disk exists for old program

Tags: windows, command-line

I have an old program that requires its input to be files on disk. The format of said files are space wasting plain ascii, and large. For both performance and storage management I keep the files zipped.

Current work flow is:

- select input files
- unzip to temp space
- run `ye_olde_fotran.exe temp\data_file.txt`
- gather results
- delete temp*.txt
- rinse, lather, repeat x 100s

This works but is clumsy and involves too much administration. How might I change this to unzip on demand, something more like `ye_old_fortran.exe < data_file.txt < unzip data_file.zip`? I have zero ability to modify the program, and a modicum of Windows batch and python scripting skills.

The computer has more than enough RAM to store the temporary data files in memory. I thought of constructing a RAM drive for the temporary files, and this will yield great performance improvements, but does nothing to alleviate the administrative overhead (read as: improve *my* performance efficiency!).

Comment: I'm sure most of it could be done with the appropriate batch commands. But you will need to provide a lot more details about your workflow ... have you already tried to script anything? It would be best if you had a go and asked specific questions when necessary.

Comment: @DavidPostill what kind of detail? it's pretty specific already, but anyway: `unzip datafile.zip -d %temp%\ && ye_old_fortran.exe %temp%\datafile.txt && del %temp%\datafile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Could you used the builtin compression of ntfs? 
Right click the text file > properties > general tab > advanced > compress contents to save disk space. > ok > apply

Then see what the properties list for size on disk. I did it to a 42MB file that dropped it down to 2.6MB on disk. Your results may vary.

This does have a slight performance hit but is transparent to your program.

EDIT: You can also do this to folders and any new items you bring in will be compressed as well.

Comment: Oh! yes this would solve the storage management part, and it's what I'll do if nothing else substantial turns up.